# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' error in python3

Tags: python, flask

I am building a heart disease prediction website. The following code is giving a typeerror. In the html file it is of type text and it gets into type int in cp.

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> number, not 'NoneType'
> I have also used pickel to open the file.

```
sc = pickle.load(open('sc.pkl', 'rb'))
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

def predict():
    lst = []
    cp = int(request.form.get('chest pain type (4 values)'))
    if cp == 0:
        lst += [1 , 0 ,0 ,0]
    elif cp == 1:
        lst += [0 ,1 ,0 ,0]
    elif cp == 2:
        lst += [0 ,0 ,1 ,0]
    elif cp >= 3:
        lst += [0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
    trestbps = int(request.form["resting blood pressure" ])
    lst += [trestbps]
    chol = int(request.form["serum cholestoral in mg/dl"])
    lst += [chol]
    fbs = int(request.form["fasting blood sugar > 120 mg/dl"])
    if fbs == 0:
        lst += [1 , 0]
    else:
        lst += [0 , 1]
    restecg = int(request.form["resting electrocardiographic results (values 0,1,2)"])
    if restecg == 0:
        lst += [1 ,0 ,0]
    elif restecg == 1:
        lst += [0 ,1 ,0]
    else:
        lst += [0 , 0,1]
    thalach = int(request.form["maximum heart rate achieved"])
    lst += [thalach]
    exang = int(request.form["exercise induced angina"])
    if exang == 0:
        lst += [1 , 0]
    else:
        lst += [0 ,1 ]
    final_features = np.array([lst])
    pred = model.predict( sc.transform(final_features))
    return render_template('checkup.html', prediction = pred)
```

The type error is at cp = int(request.form.get('chest pain type (4 values)')).
This is my html file

```
<form action="/predict"method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="chest pain type (4 values)" placeholder="chest pain type (4 values)" required="required" />
    <input type="text" name="resting blood pressure" placeholder="resting blood pressure" required="required" /> 
  <input type="text" name="serum cholestoral in mg/dl" placeholder="serum cholestoral in mg/dl" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="fasting blood sugar > 120 mg/dl" placeholder="fasting blood sugar > 120 mg/dl" required="required" />  
  <input type="text" name="resting electrocardiographic results (values 0,1,2)" placeholder="resting electrocardiographic results (values 0,1,2)" required="required" />
    <input type="text" name="maximum heart rate achieved" placeholder="maximum heart rate achieved" required="required" />
    <input type="text" name="exercise induced angina" placeholder="exercise induced angina" required="required" />
    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Predict</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This id because your code is trying to convert NoneType into an integer, which Python don't permits.

In your code if `request.form.get('chest pain type (4 values)'))` the key is not present, it'll return None which is causing the error.

If you have some default value you can use something like `request.form.get('chest pain type (4 values)', '0'))` So that if the key is not present the code returns the default value rather than None